# vim uses the same ftplugin for all file types once it has been loaded

Tags: vim

My problem with vim 7 is that it uses the keybindings of the filetype plugin tex.vim once it has been loaded, and uses it for all file types!

I think this should not be intended behaviour. Maybe I am missing something, but I have the following settings:

```
set nocompatible

"" general settings
set autoindent
set nobackup
set backspace=2
set guioptions=acei
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest,full
set mouse=a
set hidden 
set autoindent
set nobackup
set noswapfile
set backspace=2
set guioptions=acei
set tabstop=4
set linebreak
set autochdir
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Comment: Is this tex.vim or your vimrc? I interpreted it as a vimrc.

Comment: yes, it's in my vimrc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tex.vim

Change all of your `set` commands to `setlocal` commands so that the settings are local to the tex buffer.

Change all of `*map` commands to `*map <buffer>` so that mappings are local to the tex buffer.

(This is just a guess but this sounds like the problem if it is not post tex.vim)

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I was not aware of the <buffer> option.